# How to get the text value of the row that was just deleted-Jquery/Js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Delete link on clicking of which deletes the row in a table.

```
<table id="cont">
 <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>
       <label>account name</label>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
       <label>type</label>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><a class=delete href='/url/delete'>Delete</a></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

here is the js im trying to find the row that i just deleted:

```
$('.delete').on('click', function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.parent().remove();
  //how to get the <tr> that just deleted
 alert("deleted" +tr-value-deleted);
});
```

any ideas appreciated!!
Thanks..

Comment: Run the alert before you remove the row.  If you've already called `.remove()`, that data wont exist anymore.

Comment: You could consider using detach() instead of remove() if you want to remove the element(s) from the DOM but access the JQuery data later: https://api.jquery.com/detach/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by value, bit if you mean the innerHTML, you can first store it and then delete the element.

```
var deleted = $this.parent().html();
$this.parent.remove();
alert("deleted " + deleted);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cache the cell first and get the `outerHTML` later.

```
$('.delete').on('click', function(e) {
  var $p = $(this).parent();

  $p.remove();

  //how to get the <tr> that just deleted
  alert("deleted " + $p[0].outerHTML);
});
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cLrkneq5/).

Comment: Thanks all for the answers

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want as the 'value' mate!

if you want the `id` of the table you would do

```
$(this).closest('table').attr('id');
```

If you want account id or type you could easily do

```
$(this).closest('table').find('lable');
```

which should give you an array with the two elements inside